# delete list by comparing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Adding/Removing list item to/from list with JavaScript
</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function appendNewNode(){
    if(!document.getElementById) return;

    var newlisttext = document.changeform.newlist.value;  //getting text from textfield

    var mylist=document.getElementById("mylist");

    var newlistitem=document.createElement("li");   //creating new element node <li>
    var newlistitemtext=document.createTextNode(newlisttext); //creating text node with text retrieved from textfield
    newlistitem.appendChild(newlistitemtext);   //Inserting text to <li>    

    mylist.appendChild(newlistitem);    //appending <li> to <ul>

    document.changeform.newlist.value="";   //setting textfield value to blank
    document.changeform.newlist.focus();    //setting focus to textfield
}

function removeNode(){
    mylist.removeChild(mylist.lastChild);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id='mylist'>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
    </ul>


    <form name="changeform">
        <input type="text" name="newlist"  size="65">
        <input type="button" onclick="appendNewNode();" value="Append To List">


        <input type="button" onclick="removeNode();" value="Remove from List">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this code is adding new list clicking add list button but i want to delete the list after enter same text in text box and press delete to only delete that list

example suppose i want to delete list Second so i will enter "Second" in newlist text box and press delete button to only delete that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeNode(){
var newlisttext = document.changeform.newlist.value;
var mylist=document.getElementById("mylist");
var listItems = mylist.getElementsByTagName('li');  
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var elem = listItems[i];
    if (newlisttext === elem.innerText) {
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i tried alert in else but did not work properly, can you please make an alert box when user trying to delete the list which is not in the previous created lists.

Comment: did you mean     alert("something");  ?

Comment: yes i want alert box pop up when we try to delete a list which is not existed in the lists.

Comment: does alert("something"); working in the else for you?

Comment: i did that but it work only once after that if is not working, means it work once after that when i enter correct list to delete it wont delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeNode(){
        var newlisttext = document.changeform.newlist.value;
        if(newlisttext ==''){alert('Please Enter List Name to Delete!');}
        var mylist=document.getElementById("mylist");
        var listItems = mylist.getElementsByTagName('li');  
        for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            var elem = listItems[i];
            if (newlisttext === elem.innerHTML) {
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            }else{alert('This list is not found !');}
        }
}
```

alert is not working properly.